# inherited pawn office

Tags: meaning

What does "pawn office" mean in the following passage?

> Therefore, starting in the 1890s, Russian state capital started to flow into
>   Iran through this bank and was invested in loans, minting coins and other financial operations. Soon, the Loan Bank, having inherited a pawn office from Iakov Poliakov, started giving out small loans mostly secured by real estate to the local population.

I didn't find such a word in dictionaries, but I guess it is "pawnbroker".

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, "pawnbroker".  The physical location is called a "pawn shop" in the US.

Comment: In Europe, pawnbroking was a state business, with which private parties might be allowed to compete. The German word for the state pawnbroker is *Versatzamt* = *versatz* (**pawn** operation) + *amt* (bureau or administrative **office**)